# How to incorporate JS media Queries and Scroll listening?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm currently making an element visible when my nav is at the top of the page. I'd like the element to be hidden if the page gets to `max-width: 900px;`. I've tried using modernizer for JS media queries but I ca't seem to get it to work.

Code:

```
var a = $(".menu").offset().top;

function scrollListener(){
  if($(document).scrollTop() > a)
  {$('.hidden-logo').css({"opacity": "1","display": "block"});
   $('.menu').css({"margin-left": "-130px"})
  } else {
    $('.hidden-logo').css({"opacity": "0","display": "none"});
    $('.menu').css({"margin-left": "0px"})
  }
};

$(document).scroll(scrollListener);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were checking the scroll position the wrong way - I think you want the logo to disappear when the current scroll is greater than the top of the logo, not less.

I added a `msgS` div *(for demo purposes only)* that will show you the current scroll value against the top-of-menu static value. I also added a 100px fudge factor to the menu location to make it more clear in the demo when the current scroll reaches that position. *I use these temporary `msg` divs myself when working out my code, and then remove them when I've got it all sorted and ready for production.*

And this is all you need to check the media query in javascript:

```
var winmed = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 700px)");
if (winmed.matches){ //do something }
```

And that can go into a listener function exactly like your scroll listener.

```js
var gloShowLogo = true;
var a = $(".menu").offset().top;
var fudge = 100; //100px fudge factor so can SEE div disappear

function scrollListener(){
  updateScrollMsg();
  var currScroll = $(document).scrollTop();
  var topOfMenu = a+fudge;
  if( gloShowLogo && currScroll < topOfMenu ){
    $('.hidden-logo').css({"opacity": "1","display": "block"});
    $('.menu').css({"margin-left": "-130px"})
  } else {
    $('.hidden-logo').css({"opacity": "0","display": "none"});
    $('.menu').css({"margin-left": "0px"})
  }
};
function resizeListener(){
  updateMediaMsg();
  var winmed = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 500px)");
  if (winmed.matches){
    $('.hidden-logo').css({"opacity": "1","display": "block"});
    gloShowLogo = true;
  } else {
    $('.hidden-logo').css({"opacity": "0","display": "none"});
    gloShowLogo = false;
  }
}
$(window).scroll(scrollListener);
$(window).resize(resizeListener);

function updateScrollMsg(){
  $('#msgS').html( $(document).scrollTop() +' // ' + $(".menu").offset().top );
}
function updateMediaMsg(){
  var winmed = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 500px)");
  var medmsg = (winmed.matches) ? '< 500' : '> 500';
  console.log(medmsg);
  $('#msgM').html(medmsg);
}
```

```css
.menu{background:green;text-align:center;}
.content{height:200vh;background:palegreen;text-align:center;}

.hidden-logo{position:fixed;top:1vh;right:1vw;padding:15px; background:pink;z-index:2;}


#msgS{position:fixed;top:0;left:0;padding:10px;background:wheat;z-index:2;}
#msgM{position:fixed;top:40px;left:0;padding:10px;background:lightblue;z-index:2;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="menu">Menu Div</div>
<div class="content">Lengthy content Div..<br><br><br><br>100<br></div>
<div class="hidden-logo">LOGO</div>
<div id="msgS"></div>
<div id="msgM"></div>
```

#### Update:

Sorry, I had the media query a bit backwards myself - I think you want the logo to display when the screen-size is < 900px and to be hidden if wider than 900px, yes?

I added a `msgM` div so you can watch the media query kick-in -- but getting the best width for the demo was a bit of a challenge. I finally settled at 500px as a width that can be demoed *(StackOverflow resizes its StackSnippets container as the browser window resizes, which throws things into confusion at each of their resize breakpoints)*

Comment: Currently I have the scrolling working, it's just if I add a media query to fix breakpoints that everything stops working

Comment: My above demo seems to work with both. Give it a try now and see if both work together.  *You might find it helpful to use the `#msg` divs that I used in the demo to give yourself a pair of eyes as you are working this out. (Of course, console logging works just as well but this is more in-your-face and easier (for me) to track.)*

Comment: I found that your solution hits the same issue that mine did. Which is that the to functions mess with each other. I want the logo to disappear when the max-width is 900px but if you scroll and .menu is at the top of the page it will reappear, overwriting the Media Query. I'm sure their has to be an API for this. If you want to kind of get a better gist of what I'm trying to do, check out the CNBC website. When you scroll, their logo and nav changes. I don't want to do the same exact thing but that is pretty similar to what i'm trying to do.

Comment: In a case like that I would use global variables to determine whether I want to show the logo or not. So, if the screen width is < 900, then `globalShowLogo = false` and check that var in your scrollListener function. ***Answer updated with example code.***